# how can I send message from one computer to anther in java

Tags: java, networking, network-protocols

I have been searching for this for quiet some time now, basically I need to send a text message from one computer to another , the message sent should  be received by the other computer, display the text message and redirect the text just received to the computer it got the message from. Any ideas on how I can achieve this? or if there is any tutorial on this, if available .

Comment: To me the simplest way is to use sockets, one server one client. There are plenty of exmaples on the web.

Comment: You haven't been searching very well or long then... Just go to the source (Ok, it's Oracle now...): http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/networking/sockets/readingWriting.html

Comment: @Eran It is irrelevant if it is.  The homework tag is dead.  The only reason for someone to explicitly clarify that a question is homework is to justify (ludicrous [e.g. 'no loops'] or explicit [e.g. 'using only J2SE APIs']) program specifications.

Comment: @AndrewThompson: although, it's good to know if you should be coaching rather than telling: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/10811/how-to-ask-and-answer-homework-questions

Comment: @Martin  I knew there were ..a few more reasons I was missing.  To be honest, I miss the homework tag. :(

Comment: @AndersRostgaardBystrup :  Actually I didn't  knew what exactly t search for, I have been searching for the wrong things, but thank you for directing me in the right direction now.

Comment: @AndrewThompson The fact that a question is about homework is as useful as ever; what was disputed was why this fact should be stated by a tag. Tag is just not a good fit conceptually for that kind of information.

Comment: @AndrewThompson I asked since OP gave a question which is very easy to find answers to, but showed no sign of effort on his side (e.g. code snip that didn't work). A simple google search would yield the answer given below.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a kind of chat program.
For that you need some tutorials of socket programming.
you can see [Oracle Tutorial](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/networking/sockets/index.html)

Answer (score 1):

You can simply that using sockets below are the references.

1. [Lesson 1: Socket Communications](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/socket-140484.html)
2. [Lesson: All About Sockets](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/networking/sockets/index.html)

Comment: Well thank you , I got what I was looking for.